# overflow ellipsis only for last widget in the row

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Row that contains images and texts, all text widgets should fill all available spaces in the row except the last one. If the last Text doesn't fit the screen it should be shorted to three dots(TextOverflow.ellipsis).

I have this solution:

```
List<Widget> widgets = [];

for (var item in listItems) {
   widgets.add(Image.asset("images/image.png", width: 10.0, height: 10.0));
   widgets.add(Flexible(child:Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),child:Text(item.text, style: captionStyle, overflow:TextOverflow.ellipsis))));
}

//then

Expanded(child:new Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: widgets
),
```

)

But, it doesn't give needed effect

⁍ - Image

| - Row side

(*for better understanding*)

widgets are placing in this way - | ⁍ someTex... ⁍ someTex... ⁍ someTex...|

or | ⁍ so... ⁍ so... ⁍ so... ⁍ so... ⁍ so...| if a have a lot of items in the list

I need that widgets will build this way - 
|⁍someText ⁍someTex ⁍someTex ⁍ some...| **only last widget should be shorted**

BTW, i don't know how many items will come to the loop.

*Could someone explain how I can short only last widget?*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Very simple example, but here only the last text widget is clipped

```
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("Some Text", overflow:TextOverflow.ellipsis),
        Text("Some Text", overflow:TextOverflow.ellipsis),
        Text("Some Text", overflow:TextOverflow.ellipsis),
        Text("Some Text", overflow:TextOverflow.ellipsis),
        Text("Some Text", overflow:TextOverflow.ellipsis),
        Expanded(child: Text("Some Text", overflow:TextOverflow.ellipsis)),
      ],
    ),
```

So in your case, you need to wrap the last children in Expanded like this:

```
int count = 1;
for (var item in listItems) {
   widgets.add(Image.asset("images/image.png", width: 10.0, height: 10.0));
   if(count == listItems.length) widgets.add(Expanded(Flexible(child:Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),child:Text(item.text, style: captionStyle, overflow:TextOverflow.ellipsis))));
   else widgets.add(Flexible(child:Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),child:Text(item.text, style: captionStyle, overflow:TextOverflow.ellipsis))));
   count++;
}
```

Comment: tanks for the answer. But problem is - I have no idea which element will be last visible in the row. And I don't know how many items will come to the listItems.

Comment: Also every item has different text length. Looks like I need to calculate which text widget is last in the row and clipp it

Comment: nope :) @dshukertjr I will provide you an example. 
Let's say I've got from an API 10 items. First and second item have very long text size and only 2 and half items fit to the screen width, so I need to make third item clipped. With your solution tenth element will be last and clipped. I hope you got the point

Comment: @Alex And what do you want the rest of the items do? You want them to wrap and go to the next line? If so, you should use wrap widget instead of row widget in the first place.

Comment: No, @dshukertjr no need to go to next line. Need to show only items that fit to one line, even if it will be one long item (|⁍ someveryveryveryveryveryverynongtext...|)